# changing theme of android dialog

Tags: android, android-dialog

In my **Android application** I have set the **theme** of the app as

> android:Theme.Holo.Light

I created the dialog as

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(DropPicupProcess.this);
```

But when I pop up an dialogbox in the app it shows as below.
[image]

How can I change the theme of the dialog into **android:Theme.Holo.Light**.

Comment: Android 4.4. Is it maters ??????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of this

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(DropPicupProcess.this);
```

Create your dialog like this..

```
Dialog dialog=new Dialog(DropPicupProcess.this,android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light);
```

Comment: It worked. I used R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog. Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
Dialog dialog=new Dialog(DropPicupProcess.this,new ContextThemeWrapper(this,android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light));
```